# Change and reload path system variable or Windows Terminal tab or Powershell from PS script

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal

I wrote my first PowerShell script that allows me to easily switch to another version of PHP. Everything is working great except one thing. In order for the right php.exe file to be used when calling "php" in a Powershell tab in Windows Terminal, I had to change the system environment variable "path" from the previous version to the current version. So if I'm switching from 7.3 to 8.2 for example, it'll change "D:\xampp\php73" to "D:\xampp\php82". That way, if I type "php -v" for example, it uses php.exe from "D:\xampp\php82" and returns 8.2. So my script changes the variable successfully but it's not immediately available within the PowerShell window or Windows Terminal tab.

This is how I set it:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $path, 'Machine')
```

where $path is the variable containing the modified variable value. And the variable itself is indeed modified so, if I manually close the Powershell or Windows Terminal window and open it up again manually, it works fine. But my goal is to not have to do that manually. It's not a big deal of course but I'd just be surprised if this is not possible.

So I would like one of the following scenarios to work:

- (best case scenario) Reload the Path variable after changing it so it's already accessible from within the current Powershell window or Windows Terminal tab
- Automatically close and reopen either Powershell or Windows Terminal depending
- Open a new Powershell or Windows Terminal window (or tab) as my current user. Because the changes to the Path variable require elevation so, if I just do a Start-Process it opens as admin.

Is that something that can be achieved? If so, how?

I have tried opening a new Powershell window using Start-Process but that opens a new window as administrator. I've also tried different commands I found online to reload the variable, open a new Windows terminal and other but nothing worked.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe after setting, just getting ... ie `$Env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")`

Comment: Hello topsail! Thanks for your reply. I did try this within my script but it didn't do anything unfortunately. I thought it might be because the script interprets it as setting a variable within the script and not the window itself (if that makes sense).

Comment: Typically PATH is loaded when you open/start a terminal ... that's normal (and why restarting works). In linux you can use source to reload session variables  but I'm not sure about windows. Actually this question is a little unclear - you seems to have scripts and terminal windows and tabs all over the place. I was thinking you were starting php with your same script.

Comment: Oh no just one window, I'm just listing things that as potential solutions. But to simplify my question, I have one window where I run "sphp.ps1 81" and it switches to PHP 8.1 and I would like to be able to use PHP 8.1 right after the script ran and not close and reopen the window. But maybe that's not possible. The reason why is that after the script finishes I'd like to call "composer install" and for it to use the right version of PHP.

Comment: Okay gotcha. Not sure. I can find nothing clear on refreshing/reloading PATH with any simple commands that are built into powershell or cmd.exe. Seems like such a thing should exist but maybe does not.

Comment: Yeah I tried loads of things and yes it should exist but maybe it doesn't. Maybe someone will have a solution. LIke I said closing and reopening the terminal is no big deal. For it to do it automatically would be nice to have. Thanks for your help!